# How is one supposed to update a Writeable Property from the Device side (IoT Hub)?

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I have the desired property changed callback a shown below but this code does not update the reported property on the back-end (IoT Central).  This code comes from these examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-develop/concepts-developer-guide-device?pivots=programming-language-csharp)

```
private async Task OnDesiredPropertyChangedAsync(TwinCollection desiredProperties, object userContext)
 {
    JValue targetHeartbeatPeriodJson = desiredProperties["heartbeatPeriod"];
            if (targetHeartbeatPeriodJson != null)
            {
                int targetPeriod = targetHeartbeatPeriodJson.Value<int>();
                timerInterval = targetPeriod;  
                timer.Interval = timerInterval * 60000; // minutes * milliseconds

                TwinCollection reportedProperties = new TwinCollection();
                TwinCollection ackProps = new TwinCollection();

                ackProps["value"] = targetPeriod;
                ackProps["ac"] = 200;
                ackProps["av"] = desiredProperties.Version;
                ackProps["ad"] = "Desired property accepted";
                reportedProperties["heartbeatPeriod"] = ackProps;
                eventLog1.WriteEntry($"Set desired property heartbeatPeriod : {ackProps["value"]}");
                await deviceClient.UpdateReportedPropertiesAsync(reportedProperties);
            }
}
```

The device properties end up looking like this:

```
{
    "$metadata": {
       
        "heartbeatPeriod": {
            "desiredValue": 15,
            "desiredVersion": 7,
            "lastUpdateTime": "2023-08-22T09:30:45.6558675Z",
            "ackDescription": "reported value",
            "ackCode": 200
        },
        ...
    },
    ...,
    ...,
    "heartbeatPeriod": 1,
    ...
  
}
```

Am I missing something that the property is not being updated.

Comment: are you able to check updated desired properties  in [Azure](https://i.imgur.com/dAe5Ohf.png)

Comment: The device properties above come from the IoT Central device properties page. They seem to update to reflect the Ack sent from the device but the property itself doesn't seem to get updated.

Comment: is able to update the desired properties ```TwinCollection reportedProperties = new TwinCollection();
TwinCollection ackProps = new TwinCollection();
ackProps["value"] = 23.2;
ackProps["ac"] = 200; // using HTTP status codes
ackProps["av"] = 0; // not readed from a desired property
ackProps["ad"] = "reported default value";
reportedProperties["targetTemperature"] = ackProps;
await client.UpdateReportedPropertiesAsync(reportedProperties);``` using this with IoT device connection string

Comment: I think the problem is with time you set it

Comment: in visual studio [code](https://i.imgur.com/ylnDGSQ.png)

Comment: @Sampath - ok I found the problem - 'JValue targetHeartbeatPeriodJson = desiredProperties["heartbeatPeriod"];' throws an exception of there is no value in desiredProperties.

Comment: test with central working good

Comment: Hoo great, post my answer for SO Community benefits

Answer (score 1):

According to this MS-DOC Device developer guide - IoT Plug and [Play](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-develop/concepts-developer-guide-device?pivots=programming-language-csharp)

```cs
TwinCollection reportedProperties = new TwinCollection() 
            TwinCollection ackProps = new TwinCollection();
            ackProps["value"] = 24.2;   
            ackProps["ac"] = 300;    
            ackProps["av"] = 1;         
            ackProps["ad"] = "reported default value";   reportedProperties["targetTemperature"] = ackProps;
  var twinPatch = new Twin();
            twinPatch.Properties = new TwinProperties();
            twinPatch.Properties.Reported = reportedProperties;

            await deviceClient.UpdateReportedPropertiesAsync(twinPatch.Properties.Reported);

            Console.WriteLine("Reported properties updated successfully.");

            
            var twin = await deviceClient.GetTwinAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Reported properties:");
            Console.WriteLine(twin.Properties.Reported.ToJson());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            await deviceClient.CloseAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]